# MailKit seems to be encoding UNC paths like http

Tags: c#, .net, imap, mailkit

I am working with quite an old version of Mailkit/Mimekit in my company's project, 2.2.0, so it's possible this has been patched out, but I can't find any mention of it on the web.

Firstly the issues with Outlook Web, I don't know if these are related or just Outlook being janky too. I've setup a test email to be read that simply has a hyperlink for a UNC path:

> \filesrv\Areas Public\Test\Test.txt

In outlook web this seems to break the UNC path anyway, as the run command when you hover over the link shows as:

> file:///Areas Public/Test/Test.txt

If I copy right-click copy the link in Outlook web, it gives me this:

> file:///Areas%20Public/Test/Test.txt

Both missing the server name, and the latter is encoding the spaces.

On to Mailkit.  When I run IMailFolder.GetMessage(id), the TextBody is returned as this:

```
"\\\\filesrv\\Areas Public\\Test\\Test.txt<file://filesrv/Areas%20Public/Test/Test.txt>\r\n"
```

So like Outlook, the actual run command is encoding the spaces.

I've tried searching the documentation and github for references to this issue, but I come up empty.  Is there a configuration option in MailKit to prevent this, or am I reduced to fixing it retrospectively?

Comment: We have this at work, and it's an inbound filter in Exchange. Mailkit can't prevent it, because it happens long before Mailkit sees the mail.

Comment: Thanks for this, it set me down the right path of search results.  It looks like you're right, and at the same time Microsoft in Windows 10 v1803 changed the way that UNC paths with encoded characters are read, meaning they are no longer supported

Answer (score 1):

It was established that this was an inbound filter from Exchange that was causing the problem, and not MailKit. Upon further investigation, encoded UNC paths used to resolve in Windows, but since v1803 this is no longer the case:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/url-encoding-unc-paths-not-url-decoded

Therefore the only way I could resolve this was to fix the path at runtime using this:

```
link = Uri.UnescapeDataString(link);
```

Comment: This isn't a Windows issue, the path is wrong to begin with. Create a correct URL from the start instead of making the client guess what the correct path is